# Populating HTML input array with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays

I'm very much a newb when it comes to JQuery, and this arose out of an attempt to learn how to use it.

I have a form defined in which I have a series of inputs like the following:

```
<input name="Name[]">
```

I have successfully set up JQuery to clone a variable number of these and the submit works perfectly. When I submit this to PHP, I get the post data I am expecting.

```
["Name"]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=>  string(0) "" [4]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(0) "" }
```

The problem I'm running into, though, is attempting to populate these form elements with the json data returned by my PHP. When I try to set the values of these elements in the form using:

```
$('[name='+key+']', frm).val(value);
```

where (for instance) `key = Name[0]`

I haven't had much luck and get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=Name[0]]
```

Apparently it doesn't like the brackets in there? Is there a way to access elements in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take my answer as a suggestion only.
You can use the index/position of the input with `eq` function to set the value

**example**

```
$('[name="Name[]"]', frm).eq( key ).val( value );
```

or

```
$('[name="Name[]"]:eq('+key+')', frm).val( value );
```

Where key is the index/position of the input in the array `( ie: 0, 1, 2, .... )`
Read more here http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: Thank you for the response it's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the **[]** with **double backslash //** for it to work.

```
$('input[name="Name\\[0\\]"]')
```

Try this

```
key= key.replace(/\[/g, "\\\\[");
key= key.replace(/\]/g, "\\\\]");

$('[name="'+key+'"]', frm).val(value);
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, but I appreciate you taking the time to respond :)

Answer (score 1):

The name of the element stays `Name[]` in JavaScript and hence jQuery as well. Indexing the name is only required for PHP. jQuery would simply return a collection (just like if the name hadn't used `[]`) with each jQuery object accessible using the [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method.

```
<input name="Name[]" />
<input name="Name[]" />

var jsonResp = ["hello", "world"];

$.each( jsonResp, function( idx, val ) {
    $( '[name = "Name[]"]' ).eq( idx ).val( val );
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Jdv/)**

Comment: Thank you! This led me to exactly what I needed.

Comment: Apparently I can't accept two answers... despite both of them being spot-on... and I'm not sure who answered first...

Comment: @James, it's okay mate. I appreciate that you cared to comment. :)